# How to create a direct link from list page to detail page in custom module in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, url-rewrite, link

I'm a newbie in magento and this is the first time I create a module.

I have a brand module with 2 pages: list brand and brand's detail. In the list page, I want to click in a brand and then it will direct to brand's detail page but I don't know how to do this and what files I must change or create.

Can anyone show me the flow of making this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some thing like this.

1. On list page, fetch the collection and show one by one.
2. Take one by one item from collection and show it info and also put link which redirect customer to detail page.

**NOTE** For refrence you can check magento category list page.

File path 
 : app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">Product Name</a>
```